# Create folder with fso.CreateFolder

Tags: excel, vba

I need to open all files in a folder and its subfolders and save them with same name but different file extension and different location.

I divided it into two steps.

1. Create list of files and then use formula to generate output file save location
2. Loop through the list, open and then SaveAs in location given by the formula

I have code that creates a list of all files in desired locations and places it in the Excel table. Then in column F I added a formula that gives a name for the file save location.

In column A I have folder path for the source file (eg. D:\RDKU\RDKU\2022\02)

Column B has the file full name including extension (eg. RDKU_01-02-2023_OR_ORLP_0115_20230202143527_RORT_RDKU_0000305583.xls)

Column I contains the save folder (formula generated) destination.

I got stuck on `fso.CreateFolder (savePath)`.

```vb
Sub KonwertujPliki()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sourcePath As String
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim savePath As String
    Dim newFileName As String
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim fso As Object
   
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Lista") 
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        sourcePath = ws.Cells(i, "A").Value
        fileName = ws.Cells(i, "B").Value
        savePath = ws.Cells(i, "I").Value
               
        If fso.FileExists(sourcePath & "\" & fileName) Then
            newFileName = Left(fileName, Len(fileName) - 4) & ".xlsm"
            
            If Not fso.FolderExists(savePath) Then
                fso.CreateFolder (savePath)
            End If
          
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sourcePath & "\" & fileName)
            
            wb.SaveAs savePath & "\" & newFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
            
            wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
        End If
    Next i
    
    MsgBox "Files copied."
End Sub
```

I tried code from various forums, however it does not work as one full code.

Folder path name is not longer that 255 characters.

Answer (score 3):

I can think of 3 possible reasons why you can't create the path:

**(a)** Missing priviledges - if you are not allowed to create the path, you are out of luck. Nothing you can do except asking for permissing.
**(b)** Invalid names - there are some characters that are not allowed in a folder (or file) name. Again, you are out of luck and need to change the name.
**(c)** You want to create a missing folder `D:\RDKU\RDKU\2022\02`, but already one of the parent folders is missing. `fso.CreateFolder` can only create the folder `02` if the folder `2022` already exists. You can address this by creating the parent folder(s) first. The following code is an attempt to do so:

```
Sub createFolder(folder As String)
    ' Works on Windows pathes with drive letter and on UNC pathes
    ' c:\folder\subfolder\subsubfolder
    ' \\server\share\folder\subfolder\subsubfolder
    
    Dim fso As object, path As String, subfolder() As String
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    ' Split into subfolder names
    subfolder = Split(folder, "\")
    Dim startIndex As Long, i As Long
    If Left(folder, 2) = "\\" Then
        ' UNC path
        ' subfolder(0) and subfolder(1) are empty
        ' We cannot create server and share name, only folders below
        path = "\\" & subfolder(2) & "\" & subfolder(3)
        startIndex = 4
    Else
        path = subfolder(0)
        startIndex = 1
    End If
    
    For i = startIndex To UBound(subfolder)
        path = path & "\" & subfolder(i)
        If Not fso.FolderExists(path) Then
            fso.createFolder path
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```